# Advantages of SvelteKit in an environment without NodeJS?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Does it have advantages in development or for the user to use SvelteKit instead of Svelte if no NodeJS can be used on the server?

If I understand it correctly from the documentation, at least no file-based routing can be used.
What would be the alternative for Svelte to load different content with parameters (/user/4) in a SPA?

SSR or SSG are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run SvelteKit in non-node environments (e.g. CloudFlare Workers, etc).

If you are looking at building an SPA with Svelte, then I recommend SvelteKit with `adapter-static` and a `fallback` page ([see here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#spa-mode)).

This will give you client-side routing and all the other benefits of using SvelteKit without doing SSR/SSG.

Comment: I want to do this. SSR for highly interactive apps makes little sense. Has anyone tried this method with Sveltekit?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking specifically, but I use SvelteKit with SSR for multiple applications that are very interactive, is there something specific you're trying to do that you think this wouldn't work for?

Comment: I'm new to SvelteKit, and feel like the extra complexity and effort to do SSR is a waste of time. The app is all behind auth. No SEO required, so why add an extra server (I already have a node server for my API). Just serve it up static and call it a day... But, maybe it's not that hard in SvelteKit to do SSR...

Comment: You can build an SPA with Kit that has built in CSR, now SSR required 